# Accessing example arrays in step definition

Tags: scala, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-jvm

I am working on writing automation test using bdd cucumber using scala. I have following array in my Scenario Outline Examples.

```
|[name:jolly-id: 1],[name: raju-id:2]|
```

name and id can be separated by "-" or "," or";" or any separator. Above example can have some more arrays. How I can pass above array and access it in my step definition?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking. I don't know the framework you're using so maybe that's why I don't get it. But normally you can split a string into an array by a delimiter. Is that what you're asking? Like this : val arrSplit = yourString.split(",") ?

Answer (score 1):

When cuking you want your features to express WHAT you are doing and WHY its important, and not to contain anything about HOW you are doing something. Any programming constructs like arrays or tables of data are details about HOW you are doing something.

If you don't adopt this mindset you will find Cucumber features very difficult to work with, because you will keep wanting to put code things in them, but features are not code. So you end up struggling to translate things defined in the feature file that need to be become code structures (e.g. array, hash) in your step definitions.

If you want to write a technical test with tables arrays etc. use a unit test tool to write your test. You'll find that much easier, as you will be dealing with code.

If you want to get better at Cuking the simplest thing to do is to avoid all of the following

- scenario outlines
- Datatables
- regular expressions
- example groups

and focus on writing clear and simple features like

```
Scenario: Registered user can sign in
  Given I am registered
  When I sign in
  The I should be signed in
```

The only justification for writing features is to get a clear specification and understanding of what your application does that can be understood by business users as well as developers. If you don't want or need this, don't use Cucumber. If you do want this, you need to change the way you write your features and push all the HOW down into step definitions and helper methods.

Good luck :)